# How to create radio buttons in django which fields use in form and model

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

I am new to Django and Python. I want to add a radio button in my form but it doesn't work.

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect
from choicebtn.models import myChoice


class myChoiceForm(UserCreationForm):
    name=forms.CharField(max_length=55)
    TYPE_SELECT = (('0', 'Female'),('1', 'male'),)
    gender=forms.ChoiceField(widgets.RadioSelect(choices=TYPE_SELECT))

    class Meta:
           model = myChoice
           fields = ['name','gender']
```

**model.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect
from django.urls import reverse


class myChoice(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=55)
    TYPE_SELECT = (('0', 'Female'),('1', 'male'),)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=11,choices=TYPE_SELECT)
```

This only shows **dropdownlist** and **textbox**. It doesn't show radio buttons.
Please help me.

Answer (score 10):

In models.py:

```py
class myChoice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    TYPE_SELECT = (
        ('0', 'Female'),
        ('1', 'male'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=11,choices=TYPE_SELECT)
```

In forms.py:

```
class myChoiceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
           model = myChoice
           fields = ['__all__']
           widgets = {
               'gender': forms.RadioSelect()
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_SELECT, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CHOICES = [('M','Male'),('F','Female')]

Gender=forms.CharField(label='Gender', widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES))
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct way to use it.

1)models.py

```
from django import forms

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    field1 = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

2)forms.py

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect(
    attrs={'class': 'Radio'}), choices=(('apple','Apple'),('mango','Mango'),))
```

Comment: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (gender) specified for myChoice .it shows this error

Comment: Did you forget to migrate model??

Comment: No.can you give me your any successful code for a reference.

Comment: @ArpitSingh, Sorry! But It's not possible to do forms.ChoiceField into django model.  The better way, I guess, It's to use ```forms.ChoiceField(widegt=forms.RadioSelect())``` into forms.py.